# Hyperledger Fabric2.4.7 testnetwork- how can I read an other Orgs implicit private data collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

Now, I am using the fabric 2.4.7 version of the test network on ubuntu20.04. This network has an order node and two peer nodes peer0.org1 and peer0.org2.
I tried to use implicit private data collection, using the default configuration.
According to the description on the documentation https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html#implicit-private-data-collections, implicit private data collections do not have memberOnlyRead and memberOnlyWrite attributes.
When I was testing, two peers could write data in each other's implicit private data set, but they couldn't read data from each other's implicit private data set. What's the problem? How can I make it so that one peer can read another peer's content in the implicit private data set.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm wondering if there is a way to read another organization's implicitly private data collection.

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem,need set peeraddresss and tlsrootcert